# mod_rewrite mysterious subreq

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Seems like some apache module is interfering with my request uris as it suffixes ".html" to it.

My rewrite log:

```
172.16.103.1 - - [08/Mar/2012:14:56:33 +0100] [www.example.org/sid#7ff723575b58][rid#7ff724b4fc58/initial] (1) pass through /folder/subfolder/
172.16.103.1 - - [08/Mar/2012:14:56:33 +0100] [www.example.org/sid#7ff723575b58][rid#7ff724b42468/subreq] (3) [perdir /srv/www/html/project/] add path info postfix: /srv/www/html/project/folder/subfolder.html -> /srv/www/html/trustedshops/folder/subfolder.html/
172.16.103.1 - - [08/Mar/2012:14:56:33 +0100] [www.example.org/sid#7ff723575b58][rid#7ff724b42468/subreq] (3) [perdir /srv/www/html/project/] strip per-dir prefix: /srv/www/html/project/folder/subfolder.html/ -> folder/subfolder.html/
```

This merely happens on our development servers. But It's hard do compare the whole apache config. Any ideas which module could be responsible?

Comment: What are the rewriterules you are using? What urls are you using, and what to you want them to rewrite to? Just a wild stab in the dark; try adding `Options -MultiViews` to the htaccess

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Turn off MultiViews as this generates subrequests
- Ditto DirectoryIndex with a list of possiblities.
- Use the NS flag on your rewrite rules, or

  ```
  RewriteCond %{IS_SUBREQ}  t
  RwriteRule  ^             -   [L]
  ```

Comment: Great! We had MultiViews enabled in our default server config, which caused the problem.