# Why Apache mod_rewrite rewrites twice my URL?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to rewrite `/admin/page/create` URL to `/backend/www/index.php/page/create`, so I use the next Apache rewrite rule and conditions:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !backend\/www

RewriteRule admin\/(.*)$ backend/www/index.php/$1 [NS,L]
```

However, examining the rewrite log, I see Apache rewrites correctly the URL, but at the end it performs an additional rewrite considering `/page/create` URL, which doesn't match any condition, so it fails and I receive the *"No input file specified."* error.

How can I prevent Apache to perform that additional rewrite? I used `NS` flag and `RewriteCond %{IS_SUBREQ} f` condition and it also performs the subrequest.

Thank you!

```
80.29.4.44 - - [13/Jun/2013:21:40:54 +0200] [dev.daniloaz.com/sid#7f65e59b6a78][rid#7f65e5a35d60/initial] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /admin/page/create
80.29.4.44 - - [13/Jun/2013:21:40:54 +0200] [dev.daniloaz.com/sid#7f65e59b6a78][rid#7f65e5a35d60/initial] (1) pass through /admin/page/create
80.29.4.44 - - [13/Jun/2013:21:40:54 +0200] [dev.daniloaz.com/sid#7f65e59b6a78][rid#7f65e5a35d60/initial] (3) [perdir /home/daniloaz/dev.daniloaz.com/httpdocs/] add path info postfix: /home/daniloaz/dev.daniloaz.com/httpdocs/admin -> /home/daniloaz/dev.daniloaz.com/httpdocs/admin/page/create
80.29.4.44 - - [13/Jun/2013:21:40:54 +0200] [dev.daniloaz.com/sid#7f65e59b6a78][rid#7f65e5a35d60/initial] (3) [perdir /home/daniloaz/dev.daniloaz.com/httpdocs/] strip per-dir prefix: /home/daniloaz/dev.daniloaz.com/httpdocs/admin/page/create -> admin/page/create
80.29.4.44 - - [13/Jun/2013:21:40:54 +0200] [dev.daniloaz.com/sid#7f65e59b6a78][rid#7f65e5a35d60/initial] (3) [perdir /home/daniloaz/dev.daniloaz.com/httpdocs/] applying pattern 'admin\/(.*)$' to uri 'admin/page/create'
80.29.4.44 - - [13/Jun/2013:21:40:54 +0200] [dev.daniloaz.com/sid#7f65e59b6a78][rid#7f65e5a35d60/initial] (4) [perdir /home/daniloaz/dev.daniloaz.com/httpdocs/] RewriteCond: input='/admin/page/create' pattern='!-f' => matched
80.29.4.44 - - [13/Jun/2013:21:40:54 +0200] [dev.daniloaz.com/sid#7f65e59b6a78][rid#7f65e5a35d60/initial] (4) [perdir /home/daniloaz/dev.daniloaz.com/httpdocs/] RewriteCond: input='/admin/page/create' pattern='!-d' => matched
80.29.4.44 - - [13/Jun/2013:21:40:54 +0200] [dev.daniloaz.com/sid#7f65e59b6a78][rid#7f65e5a35d60/initial] (4) [perdir /home/daniloaz/dev.daniloaz.com/httpdocs/] RewriteCond: input='/admin/page/create' pattern='!backend\/www' => matched
80.29.4.44 - - [13/Jun/2013:21:40:54 +0200] [dev.daniloaz.com/sid#7f65e59b6a78][rid#7f65e5a35d60/initial] (4) [perdir /home/daniloaz/dev.daniloaz.com/httpdocs/] RewriteCond: input='/admin/page/create' pattern='((admin\/(.*)$)|(admin$))' => matched
80.29.4.44 - - [13/Jun/2013:21:40:54 +0200] [dev.daniloaz.com/sid#7f65e59b6a78][rid#7f65e5a35d60/initial] (4) [perdir /home/daniloaz/dev.daniloaz.com/httpdocs/] RewriteCond: input='false' pattern='f' => matched
80.29.4.44 - - [13/Jun/2013:21:40:54 +0200] [dev.daniloaz.com/sid#7f65e59b6a78][rid#7f65e5a35d60/initial] (2) [perdir /home/daniloaz/dev.daniloaz.com/httpdocs/] rewrite 'admin/page/create' -> 'backend/www/index.php/page/create'
80.29.4.44 - - [13/Jun/2013:21:40:54 +0200] [dev.daniloaz.com/sid#7f65e59b6a78][rid#7f65e5a35d60/initial] (3) [perdir /home/daniloaz/dev.daniloaz.com/httpdocs/] add per-dir prefix: backend/www/index.php/page/create -> /home/daniloaz/dev.daniloaz.com/httpdocs/backend/www/index.php/page/create
80.29.4.44 - - [13/Jun/2013:21:40:54 +0200] [dev.daniloaz.com/sid#7f65e59b6a78][rid#7f65e5a35d60/initial] (2) [perdir /home/daniloaz/dev.daniloaz.com/httpdocs/] strip document_root prefix: /home/daniloaz/dev.daniloaz.com/httpdocs/backend/www/index.php/page/create -> /backend/www/index.php/page/create
80.29.4.44 - - [13/Jun/2013:21:40:54 +0200] [dev.daniloaz.com/sid#7f65e59b6a78][rid#7f65e5a35d60/initial] (1) [perdir /home/daniloaz/dev.daniloaz.com/httpdocs/] internal redirect with /backend/www/index.php/page/create [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
80.29.4.44 - - [13/Jun/2013:21:40:54 +0200] [dev.daniloaz.com/sid#7f65e59b6a78][rid#7f65e5a472f0/initial/redir#1] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /backend/www/index.php/page/create
80.29.4.44 - - [13/Jun/2013:21:40:54 +0200] [dev.daniloaz.com/sid#7f65e59b6a78][rid#7f65e5a472f0/initial/redir#1] (1) pass through /backend/www/index.php/page/create
80.29.4.44 - - [13/Jun/2013:21:40:54 +0200] [dev.daniloaz.com/sid#7f65e59b6a78][rid#7f65e5a472f0/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /home/daniloaz/dev.daniloaz.com/httpdocs/] add path info postfix: /home/daniloaz/dev.daniloaz.com/httpdocs/backend/www/index.php -> /home/daniloaz/dev.daniloaz.com/httpdocs/backend/www/index.php/page/create
80.29.4.44 - - [13/Jun/2013:21:40:54 +0200] [dev.daniloaz.com/sid#7f65e59b6a78][rid#7f65e5a472f0/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /home/daniloaz/dev.daniloaz.com/httpdocs/] strip per-dir prefix: /home/daniloaz/dev.daniloaz.com/httpdocs/backend/www/index.php/page/create -> backend/www/index.php/page/create
80.29.4.44 - - [13/Jun/2013:21:40:54 +0200] [dev.daniloaz.com/sid#7f65e59b6a78][rid#7f65e5a472f0/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /home/daniloaz/dev.daniloaz.com/httpdocs/] applying pattern 'admin\/(.*)$' to uri 'backend/www/index.php/page/create'
80.29.4.44 - - [13/Jun/2013:21:40:54 +0200] [dev.daniloaz.com/sid#7f65e59b6a78][rid#7f65e5a472f0/initial/redir#1] (1) [perdir /home/daniloaz/dev.daniloaz.com/httpdocs/] pass through /home/daniloaz/dev.daniloaz.com/httpdocs/backend/www/index.php
80.29.4.44 - - [13/Jun/2013:21:40:54 +0200] [dev.daniloaz.com/sid#7f65e59b6a78][rid#7f65e5a4ce60/subreq] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /page/create
80.29.4.44 - - [13/Jun/2013:21:40:54 +0200] [dev.daniloaz.com/sid#7f65e59b6a78][rid#7f65e5a4ce60/subreq] (1) pass through /page/create
80.29.4.44 - - [13/Jun/2013:21:40:54 +0200] [dev.daniloaz.com/sid#7f65e59b6a78][rid#7f65e5a4ce60/subreq] (1) [perdir /home/daniloaz/dev.daniloaz.com/httpdocs/] pass through /home/daniloaz/dev.daniloaz.com/httpdocs/page
```

Comment: Are you trying to pass "page/create" to your index.php file?

Comment: Yes, that's it, "page/controler" is the "controller/action" I want to pass to index.php. Apache should make an internal redirect to http://dev.daniloaz.com/backend/www/index.php/page/create when I request http://dev.daniloaz.com/admin/page/create.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, I finally solved this issue using a workaround. First I tried [these solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9618865/mod-rewrite-mysterious-subreq), but subrequests were performed again and again and rewriting failed as before.

With mod_rewrite, there are small differences if you put a rule in .htaccess or in global configuration (httpd.conf, Virtualhost configuration, etc.). Subrequests are one of that differences. Just place the same rule I mentioned above in Virtualhost config file instead of .htaccess and subqueries stop and everything starts working like a charm.

I recommend this useful post to fully understand the internals of mod_rewrite before trying to solve any related to it issue: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/a-deeper-look-at-mod_rewrite-for-apache/

Comment: Removing the `MultiViews` option from `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` was at least the last part of the solution for me.

Comment: I tried this solution and dropped MultiViews.  Now I can load my.site/my-page, but all of the /js/... and /css/... URLs get redirected back to /index.php with 404.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @LawrenceI.Siden you need a `RewriteRule`. Try this: `RewriteRule .*\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp)$  -  [F,NC]`

Answer (score 0):

I just want to drop my experience here in case somebody reaches the same point I did:

I had the same problem. I tried every single answer. Every single solution. Up to the level when I can say "I really fully understand the rewrite engine". But nothing works. My URLs were still changing and showing the query string.
In some moment I said: "This is likely improbable. Must be something else". And then I tried to get the URL with WGET instead of the browser (firefox).
I did:

```
wget -qSO http://MY-THING
```

And then I realized that NOTHING from the server said the URL I saw in the browser's address bar. And even better, NOTHING in the log file!

So... how and why does it change? The obvious answer is "the browser"
I tried another browser (chrome) and works!
So what I did was to clean the history with the ["forget this site"](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/remove-websites-awesome-bar-suggestions) option and everybody happy.

Now I don't know WHEN I fixed it. Might be the -Multiviews thing, or the rule's flags, or the INTERNAL REDIRECT part... I don't really know. But probably the solution wasn't there.