# Fail to rewrite url and append parameters in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here's my .htaccess rule which works:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}   ^/work
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}   ^foo=bar$
RewriteRule  ^(.*)$   /test.php
```

Unfortunately, if I want to append some parameters to the rewritten path it doesn't work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}   ^/work
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}   ^foo=bar$
RewriteRule  ^(.*)$   /test.php?par=new
```

If I add `[R=301]` then it works too, but I don't want to add it because I don't want the user see the address changed:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}   ^/work
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}   ^foo=bar$
RewriteRule  ^(.*)$   /test.php?par=new   [R=301]
```

Why isn't the 2nd one working? Did I miss something?
Environment:
Ubuntu 12.04, XAMPP(Apache/2.4.4)

Thanks.

**Edit 1**

Per [Internal URL rewrite no longer working after upgrading Apache to 2.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20023601/internal-url-rewrite-no-longer-working-after-upgrading-apache-to-2-4), this seems to be a bug related to Apache 2.4.

.htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^foo=bar$ 
RewriteRule ^work/(.*)$ /test.php?par=new   [L]
```

log when execute `curl http://alison/work/?foo=bar -v`

```
[Thu Aug 28 15:36:39.728123 2014] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 14865] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:33092] 127.0.0.1 - - [alison/sid#1b438a0][rid#1e05820/initial] [perdir /home/amareknight/Projects/firstmg/root/alison/] strip per-dir prefix: /home/amareknight/Projects/firstmg/root/alison/work/ -> work/
[Thu Aug 28 15:36:39.728141 2014] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 14865] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:33092] 127.0.0.1 - - [alison/sid#1b438a0][rid#1e05820/initial] [perdir /home/amareknight/Projects/firstmg/root/alison/] applying pattern '^work(.*)$' to uri 'work/'
[Thu Aug 28 15:36:39.728170 2014] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 14865] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:33092] 127.0.0.1 - - [alison/sid#1b438a0][rid#1e05820/initial] [perdir /home/amareknight/Projects/firstmg/root/alison/] RewriteCond: input='foo=bar' pattern='^foo=bar$' => matched
[Thu Aug 28 15:36:39.728186 2014] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 14865] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:33092] 127.0.0.1 - - [alison/sid#1b438a0][rid#1e05820/initial] [perdir /home/amareknight/Projects/firstmg/root/alison/] rewrite 'work/' -> '/test.php?par=new'
[Thu Aug 28 15:36:39.728201 2014] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 14865] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:33092] 127.0.0.1 - - [alison/sid#1b438a0][rid#1e05820/initial] split uri=/test.php?par=new -> uri=/test.php, args=par=new
[Thu Aug 28 15:36:39.728218 2014] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 14865] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:33092] 127.0.0.1 - - [alison/sid#1b438a0][rid#1e05820/initial] [perdir /home/amareknight/Projects/firstmg/root/alison/] internal redirect with /test.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[Thu Aug 28 15:36:39.728420 2014] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 14865] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:33092] 127.0.0.1 - - [alison/sid#1b438a0][rid#1fa24a0/subreq] [perdir /home/amareknight/Projects/firstmg/root/alison/] strip per-dir prefix: /home/amareknight/Projects/firstmg/root/alison/work/index.html -> work/index.html
[Thu Aug 28 15:36:39.728436 2014] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 14865] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:33092] 127.0.0.1 - - [alison/sid#1b438a0][rid#1fa24a0/subreq] [perdir /home/amareknight/Projects/firstmg/root/alison/] applying pattern '^work(.*)$' to uri 'work/index.html'
[Thu Aug 28 15:36:39.728457 2014] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 14865] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:33092] 127.0.0.1 - - [alison/sid#1b438a0][rid#1fa24a0/subreq] [perdir /home/amareknight/Projects/firstmg/root/alison/] RewriteCond: input='par=new' pattern='^foo=bar$' => not-matched
[Thu Aug 28 15:36:39.728473 2014] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 14865] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:33092] 127.0.0.1 - - [alison/sid#1b438a0][rid#1fa24a0/subreq] [perdir /home/amareknight/Projects/firstmg/root/alison/] pass through /home/amareknight/Projects/firstmg/root/alison/work/index.html
[Thu Aug 28 15:36:39.728624 2014] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 14865] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:33092] 127.0.0.1 - - [alison/sid#1b438a0][rid#1f9a360/subreq] [perdir /home/amareknight/Projects/firstmg/root/alison/] strip per-dir prefix: /home/amareknight/Projects/firstmg/root/alison/work/index.html.var -> work/index.html.var
[Thu Aug 28 15:36:39.728640 2014] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 14865] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:33092] 127.0.0.1 - - [alison/sid#1b438a0][rid#1f9a360/subreq] [perdir /home/amareknight/Projects/firstmg/root/alison/] applying pattern '^work(.*)$' to uri 'work/index.html.var'
[Thu Aug 28 15:36:39.728660 2014] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 14865] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:33092] 127.0.0.1 - - [alison/sid#1b438a0][rid#1f9a360/subreq] [perdir /home/amareknight/Projects/firstmg/root/alison/] RewriteCond: input='par=new' pattern='^foo=bar$' => not-matched
[Thu Aug 28 15:36:39.728675 2014] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 14865] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:33092] 127.0.0.1 - - [alison/sid#1b438a0][rid#1f9a360/subreq] [perdir /home/amareknight/Projects/firstmg/root/alison/] pass through /home/amareknight/Projects/firstmg/root/alison/work/index.html.var
[Thu Aug 28 15:36:39.728741 2014] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 14865] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:33092] 127.0.0.1 - - [alison/sid#1b438a0][rid#1fa24a0/subreq] [perdir /home/amareknight/Projects/firstmg/root/alison/] strip per-dir prefix: /home/amareknight/Projects/firstmg/root/alison/work/index.php -> work/index.php
[Thu Aug 28 15:36:39.728760 2014] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 14865] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:33092] 127.0.0.1 - - [alison/sid#1b438a0][rid#1fa24a0/subreq] [perdir /home/amareknight/Projects/firstmg/root/alison/] applying pattern '^work(.*)$' to uri 'work/index.php'
[Thu Aug 28 15:36:39.728779 2014] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 14865] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:33092] 127.0.0.1 - - [alison/sid#1b438a0][rid#1fa24a0/subreq] [perdir /home/amareknight/Projects/firstmg/root/alison/] RewriteCond: input='par=new' pattern='^foo=bar$' => not-matched
[Thu Aug 28 15:36:39.728794 2014] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 14865] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:33092] 127.0.0.1 - - [alison/sid#1b438a0][rid#1fa24a0/subreq] [perdir /home/amareknight/Projects/firstmg/root/alison/] pass through /home/amareknight/Projects/firstmg/root/alison/work/index.php
```

I have index.php located in /work directory and it seems Apache just ignores the INTERNEL_REDIRECT and loads the index.php.

Comment: have you tried using `[QSA,L]`? Also if you use `QSA` and the URL previously had `?par=new` in it, you don't even need to append it again, as it will be done automatically.

Comment: Are there more rules in your .htaccess?

Comment: @Prix The original URL doesn't have `?par=new`, I just want to append it.

Answer (score 1):

You can have your rule like this in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^foo=bar$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^work /test.php?par=new [L,QSA,NC]
```

This will internally rewrite a URL like `/work/abc?foo=bar` to `/test.php?foo=bar&par=new`

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Actually I think it's a bug related to Apache 2.4 because the same .htaccess works on Apache 2.2.

Comment: What is the URL you are seeing in your browser and where is this .htaccess located?

Comment: I don't use browser to test, I just use curl: `curl "http://alison/work/?foo=bar" -v`

Comment: Yes curl is better to test than browsers since it doesn't cache results.

Comment: Per https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53929 this issue appears again in 2.4.6 and fixed in 2.4.9, I'll give it a shot. Thanks for your help.

Comment: ok for testing if you add `R` in the rule to make it: `RewriteRule ^work /test.php?par=new [L,QSA,NC,R]` does it redirect to: `http://alison/test.php?foo=bar&par=new` ?

Comment: Yes, `R` works, but that will return a 302 redirect and I don't want the visitor see `http://alison/test.php?foo=bar&par=new` in his address bar.

Comment: Also, if I specify "index.php" when `curl` then it works too. `curl "http://alison/work/index.php?foo=bar" -v`

Comment: So `http://alison/work/index.php?foo=bar` gets rewritten but `http://alison/work/?foo=bar` gives 404?

Comment: `http://alison/work/index.php?foo=bar` get rewritten to `http://alison/test.php?foo=bar&par=new` but `http://alison/work/?foo=bar` actually returns `http://alison/work/index.php`, I posted the full log in my question.

Comment: No, this is the only .htaccess I have. I've tested the same project on 2.2.16 and it works.

Comment: Ok try putting `Options -MultiViews` on top of your .htaccess and retest

Comment: @AmareKnight do you really have no other rules on your `.htaccess` file? it looks to me that the first rule is processed and then it loops on the next rules, can you update your question with your `.htaccess` exactly as it is on the root folder? Also look inside the work folder and make sure there is no other `.htaccess` with `ls -la` to make sure your viewing files that start with a dot.

Comment: @AmareKnight instead of `[L,QSA,NC]` try `[END,QSA,NC]` which should make HTTPD also stop any subsequent rewrites, giving you're using version 2.4+

Comment: @Prix That's exactly why it's a bug with Apache 2.4.6. You're right about Apache continues loop, but it's trying to find index.html, index.html.var, index.php... All these files are only defined in httpd.conf as DirectoryIndex by default.

Comment: @AmareKnight and have you upgraded it or tried to use the END flag?

Comment: I tried reverting back to 2.2.16 but haven't tried upgrading to 2.4.9.

Comment: @AmareKnight could you update your question with an exact copy of your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: In addition to disabling `MultiViews` also use this line on top of your .htaccess `DirectoryIndex index.php`

Comment: @Prix Can't edit any posts now... Alert "Page Not Found"

Comment: @anubhava This works, but what about other index.htmls?

Comment: Can you have `index.php` and/or `index.html` both in same directory? If yes then use **`DirectoryIndex index.php index.html`**

Comment: Upgrade to 2.4.10 and problem solved too. Definitely a bug with Apache itself. Thanks all the same @Prix

Comment: @AmareKnight we do try to exhaust possibilities before calling it bug ;) but glad you got it solved.