# Rewrite rules not working as expected with apache 2.4.23

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am using Virtual Box VM and Vagrant to create an Ubuntu 14 box and have no choice but to use apache 2.4.23 as a web server. My app has a front controller (index.php) that is handles most of the work of the site in terms of routing, but there are some standard files that users can access as well.

There are other devs on my team that still have apache 2.4.20 and their boxes are working exactly as expected.

My problem is that the rewrite rules aren't acting as expected. Here is the .htaccess file before upgrading to 2.4.23:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.php/$1 [L]

    Options All -Indexes

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Here is the apache2.conf:

```
# Security
ServerTokens OS
ServerSignature On
TraceEnable On

ServerName "my-local"
ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}
Timeout 120
KeepAlive Off
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 15

User www-data
Group www-data

AccessFileName .htaccess
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>

<Directory /var/www/>
  Options FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride None
  Require all granted
</Directory>


HostnameLookups Off
ErrorLog "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
LogLevel warn
EnableSendfile Off

#Listen 80


Include "/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/*.load"
Include "/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/*.conf"
Include "/etc/apache2/ports.conf"

LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combi$
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

IncludeOptional "/etc/apache2/conf.d/*.conf"
IncludeOptional "/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/*"
```

I can access the site as long as I add `R` to the Rewrite rule, but that is clearing out POST. I tried using GET as a quick workaround, but some of my forms end up with request strings that are too long for apache.

I need to know if there is a flaw in these configs that I am unable to see or if there is a workaround that I am unaware of.

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f ... RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.php/$1 [R,L]` - I suspect that's going to end up as a terminal loop, you probably want something like `index.php?path=$1`. Alternatively you could look at Apache's `FallbackResource`.

Comment: @anubhava I get routed to the correct URL but I get a white page that says file not found

Comment: @CD001 both of your suggestions route properly in terms of what I'm seeing in the url, but I am getting this error on the page: "The page isn’t redirecting properly. The server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete."

Comment: I am just going to the domain: local.myapp.com, also I commented out the regular rewrite rule when I tried the Fallback

Comment: *"The page isn’t redirecting properly. The server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete."* - sounds like a terminal loop, something looping recursively, forever.

Comment: @CD001 You are right, but the weird thing is that other devs on my team using 2.4.20 aren't having this problem at all

Comment: @anubhava, I just set it to AllowOverride All and I'm still getting the same file not found when I remove the R flag

Comment: What is status code you're getting back 200 or 404?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following got me past the problem:

- Re-provisioned to Ubuntu 16
- Added `custom_fragment: /var/www/AudiMoc/htaccess` to apache in my
  config.yaml

in htaccess:

```
## Custom fragment.
## This file can be refered to by the 'apache:' section config.yaml in case of a bug described by
## https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17095981/why-apache-mod-rewrite-rewrites-twice-my-url?rq=1.
## If you use it, then remove or rename /var/www/AudiMoc/.htaccess.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1
    #Without this, rewrite_mod will think that '/' matches the directory /var/www/AudiMoc/.
    RewriteRule ^/$ /index.php [L]
    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

There was a bug for apache2.4.23-5 that made the [R,L] a must, and the reason I couldn't get around it more easily was because I have to have my dev environment on  virtual box using puphpet to build the config. Puphpet.com only had one version of apache2 in the repository they reference, so I couldn't get around the bug.

The custom fragment allowed me to get around the problem.